# After Migration Layer Navigation not Showing Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.3.1

Tags: migration, magento2.3.1

After the migration of magento 1 to magento 2.3.1 Layernavigation not showing on any category pages. I have checked category is set to `Anchor:yes`. Also Price attribute value `visible on layered navigation:yes`

I look into the log files but not generate any logs.
Any kind of help will appreciated.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192323/attribute-not-shown-in-layer-navigation-after-migration

Comment: Already seen, but not luck.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? @SanjayGohil